# How DCT-coeffitients change after shifting the image in the spatial domain?

Tags: image-processing, compression, jpeg, image-compression, dct

Suppose we have an image **I** of dimentions (8*n)x(8*n), and let *m=n-1*. Consider a cropped image **J** of dimentions (8*m)x(8*m) obtained from **I** by reducing *t* rows form above, *8-t* rows from below, *k* columns from left, and *8-k* columns form right.

[image: images]

[image: border]

If *t* and *k* both equal 0, or both equal 8, then DCT matrix of **J** is a "submatrix" of DCT matrix of **I**. In other cases the coefficients are very different. Is there any connection between DCT(I) and DCT(J)? I mean, other than DCT(J)=DCT(crop(IDCT(DCT(I)))). Something more direct and useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

Instead of going into detail here, I refere to a similar question on math.stackexchange: [How does a cropping of a 2D matrix/image affect its DCT transform?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760010/how-does-a-cropping-of-a-2d-matrix-image-affect-its-dct-transform). The accepted answer also gives an intuitive example of why there is no simple connection between DCT(I) and DCT(J) by considering the one-dimensional case.